# Strange alignment in declarations with listing for JavaScript code

Tags: listings, javascript

I'm trying to fine-tune my listing style for JavaScript and I can't understand why:

1. Declarations like "let b = a+1;" shows like "let b =a+1;", so the space after the '=' symbol is eliminated
2. Closing rounded brakets have a different color from the opening ones

I share the code that defines my style. I got it partially online and than started to modify it, so I probably messed up somenthing:

```
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={color=captioncolor, small,tt}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={color=captioncolor, small, tt}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+17pt\relax}{0.4pt}\vskip1pt#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={sf},labelsep=space,labelfont=bf}

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
    alsoletter={.},
    
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{jsextkeywords}\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\color{identifiers},
    sensitive=true,
    stringstyle=\color{string}\ttfamily,
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[d]',
    morestring=[s][\color{string}\ttfamily]{`}{`},
    commentstyle=\color{red}\itshape,
    morecomment=[l][\color{allcomment}]{//},
    morecomment=[s][\color{allcomment}]{/*}{*/},
    morecomment=[s][\color{allcomment}]{/**}{*/},
    
}

  \lstset{
   basicstyle=\normalsize\linespread{1.1}\footnotesize\ttfamily,
   language=JavaScript,
   frame=top,frame=bottom,
   breaklines=true,
   columns=fullflexible,
   showstringspaces=false,
   tabsize=2,
   upquote = true,
   numbers=left,
   numberstyle=\tiny,
   stepnumber=1,
   numbersep=5pt,
   numberblanklines=false,
   xleftmargin=17pt,
   framexleftmargin=17pt,
   framexrightmargin=17pt,
   framexbottommargin=5pt,
   framextopmargin=5pt,
   alsoother={.},
   captionpos=t,
   literate=
            *{\{}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{\{}}}{1}% punctuators
            {\}}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{\}}}}{1}%
            {(}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{(}}}{1}%
            {)}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{)}}}{1}%
            {[}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{[}}}1%
            {]}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{]}}}1%
            {...}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{...}}}1%
            {;}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{;}}}1%
            {,}{{\textcolor{antiquefuchsia}{,}}}1%
            {>}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>}}}1%
            {<}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{<}}}1%
            {<=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{<=}}}1%
            {>=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>=}}}1%
            {==}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{==}}}1%
            {!=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{!=}}}1%
            {===}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{===}}}1%
            {!==}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{!==}}}1%
            {+}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{+}}}1%
            {-}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{-}}}1%
            {*}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{*}}}1%
            {\%}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{\%}}}1%
            {++}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{++}}}1%
            {--}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{--}}}1%
            {<<}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{<<}}}1%
            {>>}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>>}}}1%
            {>>>}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>>>}}}1%
            {=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{=}}}1%
            {&}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{&}}}1%
            {|}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{|}}}1%
            {^}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{^}}}1%
            {!}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{!}}}1%
            {~}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{~}}}1%
            {&&}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{&&}}}1%
            {||}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{||}}}1%
            {?}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{?}}}1%
            {:}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{:}}}1%
            {=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{=}}}1%
            {+=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{+=}}}1%
            {-=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{-=}}}1%
            {*=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{*=}}}1%
            {\%=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{\%=}}}1%
            {<<=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{<<=}}}1%
            {>>=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>>=}}}1%
            {>>>=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{>>>=}}}1%
            {&=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{&=}}}1%
            {|=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{|=}}}1%
            {^=}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{^=}}}1%
            {=>}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{=>}}}1%
            {\\b}{{\textcolor{ballblue}{\\b}}}1% escape sequences
            {\\t}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\t}}}{1}%
            {\\n}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\n}}}{1}%
            {\\v}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\v}}}{1}%
            {\\f}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\f}}}{1}%
            {\\r}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\r}}}{1}%
            {\\"}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\"}}}{1}%
            {\\'}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\'}}}{1}%
            {\\}{{\textcolor{apricot}{\\}}}{1}%
            {0}{{\textcolor{apricot}{0}}}{1}% numbers
            {1}{{\textcolor{apricot}{1}}}{1}%
            {2}{{\textcolor{apricot}{2}}}{1}%
            {3}{{\textcolor{apricot}{3}}}{1}%
            {4}{{\textcolor{apricot}{4}}}{1}%
            {5}{{\textcolor{apricot}{5}}}{1}%
            {6}{{\textcolor{apricot}{6}}}{1}%
            {7}{{\textcolor{apricot}{7}}}{1}%
            {8}{{\textcolor{apricot}{8}}}{1}%
            {9}{{\textcolor{apricot}{9}}}{1}%
            {.0}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.0}}}{2}%
            {.1}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.1}}}{2}%
            {.2}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.2}}}{2}%
            {.3}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.3}}}{2}%
            {.4}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.4}}}{2}%
            {.5}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.5}}}{2}%
            {.6}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.6}}}{2}%
            {.7}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.7}}}{2}%
            {.8}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.8}}}{2}%
            {.9}{{\textcolor{apricot}{.9}}}{2},%
   emphstyle={\color{express}}, % express
   emphstyle={[2]\color{nodejs}}, % node.js
   emphstyle={[3]\color{testing}}, % jasmine ...
   numberstyle=\normalfont\tiny\textcolor{linenumber} % line number
}
```

This is the example code I'm tring to use:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language = JavaScript]
"use strict" ;
function example(x) {
    let a = 1 ;
    console.log(a);    // 1
    console.log(b);    // ReferenceError: b is not defined
    console.log(c);    // undefined
    if(x > 1) {
        let b = a+1;
        var c = a*2;
    }
    console.log(a);    // 1
    console.log(b);    // ReferenceError: b is not defined
    console.log(c);    // 2
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Here's how I see the compiled code:
[image]

Thank you for your time and for the help!

Comment: Please try to combine and extend your code snippets to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). It is a lot easier to just copy one code to reproduce the problem and test ideas, than to first combine two code snippets and then guess what else is needed, before being able to work on it. So you would reach more people.